# wiper control wiring diagram

Tags: windshield-wipers, control

Can any one can help me to connect mitsuba is-4301 wiper control.
It is  24v and 6 pin.it is used in mitsubishi canter.
I need diagram to how to connect the control relay.
Thank you.

Comment: The standard wiring should normally have a plug that holds all the wires correctly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!